# connecting to a regular socket server from a web socket server (autobahn)

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, autobahn

i am writing an intermediary web socket server so that it can forward messages directly to my existing socket server.

what i am naively thinking is that on the

```
   def onOpen(self):
      #initialize socket client and run in a while true loop
```

i can setup the socket client there and listen forever with a `while true`, and do `self.sendMessage(...)` for any `recv()` data received from the socket client back to the websocket client.

would something like this work? are there better ways to do this? what i am worried about is that the `while true` will be blocking for everyone.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutobahnPython has that built in. Wrap any existing stream-based protocol (such as VNC, SSH, IRC, IMAP, ...) **over** WebSocket - please see [here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/wrapping).